# Check box active and diactive in pythonGTK using glade

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, glade

I want to write the code for the following image:

[image]

I want to tell if tick is true be able to enter user and pass if the tick of Login is false not be able to enter user and pass. This is `xml`  glade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.0 -->
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkLayout" id="layout1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkCheckButton" id="checkbutton1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Login</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <property name="width_request">150</property>
            <property name="height_request">30</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">False</property>
            <property name="use_action_appearance">False</property>
            <property name="xalign">0</property>
            <property name="draw_indicator">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">10</property>
            <property name="y">10</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="width_request">150</property>
            <property name="height_request">30</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="invisible_char">●</property>
            <property name="placeholder_text">Username</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">10</property>
            <property name="y">40</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry2">
            <property name="width_request">150</property>
            <property name="height_request">30</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="invisible_char">●</property>
            <property name="placeholder_text">Password</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="x">170</property>
            <property name="y">40</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect a callback to the Login CheckButton that toggles the sensitivity of your two Entry widgets by calling the widget `set_sensitive(sensitive)` method on them.

From the [GTK2 docs](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--set-sensitive):

> `def set_sensitive(sensitive)`
>
> **sensitive** :  if True make the widget sensitive
>
> The `set_sensitive()` method sets the "sensitive" property of the widget
>   to the value specified by **sensitive**. If **sensitive** is True the widget
>   will be sensitive and the user can interact with it. An insensitive
>   widget appears "grayed out" and the user can't interact with it.
>   Insensitive widgets are known as "inactive", "disabled", or "ghosted"
>   in some other toolkits.

I can post a small example in GTK2, if that helps.